# Replace a regular expression (regexp) variable next to an integer

Tags: regex

I want to modify the copyright year.

This is the string I am looking for:

```
Copyright Company XXX YYY ZZZ 1999 - 2010
```

I search this string with that regexp:

```
([cC]opyright([A-Za-z ]?){0,}[0-9]{4}([A-Za-z ])?(-)?([A-Za-z ])?)[0-9]{4}
```

I want to replace the second year with 2017. But replacing with $12017 does not work, obviously. And $1 2017 adds a space i do not want.

What is the replace expression to get

```
    Copyright Company XXX YYY ZZZ 1999 - 2017
```

The thing is that it might not always be YYYY - YYYY (with one space between them). It could be YYYY-YYYY, YYYY -YYYY etc...

Comment: Depends on regex flavor. Try `${1}2017`

Comment: `$1(2017)` might also work (works in Notepad++)

Comment: In NPP, POSIX like backreference should work, `\12017`

Comment: `s/^([cC]opyright[ \t\w\d-]+)(\d\d\d\d)\s*$/\12017/` works in most flavors. [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/1fRdCK/2)

Comment: Have you tried $12017?  regex101 has a few flavors.  Try them out: https://regex101.com/r/6r0BtW/1

Comment: I forgot to try that obvious ${1} :) Thank you very much all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to my question is simply:

```
${1}
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- Find: `(?i)(copyright .+?\d{4}\s*-\s*)\d{4}$`
- Replace: `${1}2017`

or:

- Find: `(?i)copyright .+?\d{4}\s*-\s*\K\d{4}$`
- Replace: `2017`

Comment: The `(?i)(?=copyright .+?\d{4}\s*-\s*)\d{4}$` regex is wrong, it will never match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew:True